# Retain multiple fragmens on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

First of all, I know that I can retain a single fragment with `setRetainInstance(true);` and retrieving from `FragmentManager` when `savedInstanceState`.

But my situation is that I have three fragments in my Activity, which I "swap" using transaction, depending on user actions.
I can also recreate the current fragment, saving the flag within `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to recover it when the user rotates the screen.

My problem comes when the user rotates the screen, being in one fragment and then click to go to previous fragment. Since the only fragment I can recover is the active fragment, I cannot show to the previous fragment without recreaing it (loosing all the information I had).

Here is my code. Also if this is not a good sollution, I would apreciate any tips.

```
private Fragment1 fragment1;
private Fragment2 fragment2;
private Fragment3 fragment3;
private String currentFragmentTAG;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight);

    ...

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // HOW TO RECOVER ALL FRAGMENTS??
        fragment1 = ??;
        fragment2 = ??;
        fragment3 = ??;

        String tag = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVED_FRAGMENT);
        Fragment savedFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        replaceFragment(savedFragment, tag, null);
    }
}

// Here, in other funcions, I initialize fragments and show one of them depending of user actions
// I use replaceFragment function to "swap" fragments.

private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag, Map<String, Parcelable> objectsToBundle) {
    if (fragment != null && !tag.equals(currentFragmentTAG)) {
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if (objectsToBundle != null && !objectsToBundle.isEmpty()) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            for (Map.Entry<String, Parcelable> entry : objectsToBundle.entrySet()) {
                bundle.putParcelable(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }

            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        }

        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_weight_container, fragment, tag);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();

        currentFragmentTAG = tag;
    }
}
```

In my fragments I use `setRetainInstance(true)`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. I just need to use `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag)` when perform the transaction in my `replaceFragment` function. This way all the fragments used in my activity will be retaines and could be recovered from `FragmentManager`

```
...
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
...
```

So this is the way I can recover them (if already instantiated)

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    mWeightMainFragment = (WeightMainFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(WeightMainFragment.TAG);
    mWeightAddFragment = (WeightAddFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(WeightAddFragment.TAG);
    mWeightChartFragment = (WeightChartFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(WeightChartFragment.TAG);

    currentFragmentTAG = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVED_FRAGMENT);
    Fragment savedFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTAG);
    replaceFragment(savedFragment, currentFragmentTAG, null);
}
```

> Bonus: I'm also using popBackStack() to undo transcactions instead of replace again with the back stack fragment.